# mdx with row of parallel days of prev weeks

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to write a mdx that contain rows of parallel days. The problem is that my hyrarchy is by month. That's my query, but know i need to make it dynamcly. What is the right syntax?

[image: The Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to programmatically go back 7 days then you can apply the `lag` function to the end of a date member:

```
[Date time Online].[Date Key].&[201602152300].lag(7)
```

If you need to feed `now()` into an mdx script this pattern is helpful:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now()
     ,'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']' 
  SET [Today] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    ) 
...
```

Comment: i want to know how to replace the hard code date to current date like now()